# Workaround Angular url params bug in ngxRestangular

Tags: angular, ngx-restangular

I'm trying to work around this issue here [in which the plus sign is being left as is in the query parameters which get interpreted as spaces on the server instead](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11058).

The problem is that I'm using [ngxRestangular](https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ngx-restangular) and so am not clear on how to work around this.

I tried using `addFullRequestInterceptor` as below but it caused all of my query params to be double encoded.

```
this.restangular.withConfig((restConfig) = > {
    restConfig.addFullRequestInterceptor((element, operation, path, url, headers, params) => {
        for (let param in params) {
            params[param] = encodeURIComponent(params[param]);
        }
        return {params, headers, element}
    });
})
```

I've also tried adding an [HttpInterceptor exactly as described in the Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) but that doesn't appear to be firing.

How do I go about working around this issue using this library?

Comment: I think the problem is that `+` is not encoded as `%20`. So I would just do a search and replace of `+` to a space, since you've already stated it will be encoded again.

Comment: @cgTag The issue is it needs to be encoded as a plus sign, `%2B`, not as a space. I believe my link to the angular issue outlines that well but let me know if that isn't clear and I'll update the question.